# Por que um alinhamento interno de um botão <button> fica diferente de um link <a>, mesmo usando a mesma classe?

Tags: css, html5

Bem, eu criei uma classe chamada `.btn`, onde eu queria usá-la tanto para `button` como para `a`. Por isso eu forcei algumas coisas nessa classe, para resetar o estilo original, tanto do `button` como do `a`.

Por exemplo, no `a` eu removi o `text-decoration`. No `button`, forcei a mudança do `background` e `border`. Até aqui tudo bem.

O problema é que eu estou notando que o elemento `button`, mesmo usando o `-webkit-appearence: none`, apresenta um comportamento diferente em relação ao alinhamento do texto interno, conforme o teste abaixo:

```css
.btn{
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0px #666;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 4px;    
    background-color: #efefef;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: box-shadow .1s ease-out, border-color .3s linear;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
   display: inline-block;
 
    min-height: 55px;
    font-size: 14px;
   
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #222;
   background-image: none;

    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    font-family: Arial;

}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
  Eu sou um &lt;Button&gt;
</button>

<a class="btn">
    Eu sou um &lt;A&gt;
</a>
```

Eu vou colocar a  imagem também, pra mostrar como ficou a renderização no meu Google Chrome:

[image: Button e A, alinhamentos diferentes para a mesma classe]

Agora fica minha dúvida:

- Que propriedade faz com que o `button` alinhe os textos no meio, enquanto o `a` não?
- Existe uma forma de resetar essa alinhamento padrão do `button`? Minha intenção era deixar os dois centralizados, mas mais importante do que isso, quero saber se existe uma propriedade do `button` fez ficar alinhado ao centro.

<sub>**Observação**: A pergunta não tem o apenas o intuito de saber como alinhar o texto ao centro, mas saber a fundo sobre o que ocasionou a diferença citada acima, já que eu usei o mesmo estilo para todos.</sub>

<sub>**Observação 2:** Eu poderia usar `inline-flex` e combinar com `justify-content: center; align-itens: center`, mas não é essa a resposta que quero, pois isso já estou colocando ela na pergunta. Quero saber especificamente sobre os detalhes apresentados acima, e não apenas um "suporte para o problema do alinhamento"</sub>

Comment: Já verificou que estilos são atribuídos por ao <button> e <a> por defeito em qualquer browser.

Comment: @JorgeCosta eu copiei os estilos do user-agent todo e apliquei ao seletor `a {...}` nada acontece, isso ai é comportamento do elemento Button como se isolasse o texto para, diferente do A que o texto interno acompanha o `vertical-align: top`

Comment: mas verificou que o button tem line-height, no safari em macOS é line-height: 13px;

Comment: @JorgeCosta até copiando o line-height do user-agent para `<button>` o resultado é o mesmo.

Comment: Para testar retire o min-height: 55px;   e coloque   line-height: 3;    padding: 0px;

Comment: @JorgeCosta se você colocar `min-height: 1000px` no button, ele fica com tudo no meio, da mesma forma. Não creio que seja apenas o `line-height`.

Comment: Caro @JorgeCosta tirar o `min-height` não explica como o porque o texto no `<button>` alinha verticalmente para o centro. Aqui ninguém tá procurando soluções de como resolver, mas sim entender o porque isto ocorre, como o autor da pergunta já explicou na propria pergunta.

Comment: Sim eu também estou a tentar perceber e não resolver

Comment: Caro @JorgeCosta entendo, mas seus comentários foram todos sobre tira isso, faz aquilo, acaba por fazer entender que esta tentando aplicar soluções e não tentar entender o comportamento do box-model: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html, mas acho que já estamos esclarecidos de tudo :)

Comment: Estava verificando o que o próprio browser aplica por defeito, caso fosse para encontrar a solução me limitaria a aplicar as soluções já encontradas em frameworks como bootstrap. Mas já que está esclarecido sobre a questão agradeço que coloque uma resposta cabal para a pergunta e assim partilhar com todos.

Answer (score 1):

**Atualizado - 11/08/2018**

Depois de muita pesquisa apesar de entender a questão de várias formas pesquisei e obtive uma resposta mais plausível com fontes para sua questão.

A resposta é do [Cubed Eye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495876/cubed-eye) usuário do Stack overflow.

Em primeiro lugar, a principal questão aqui é que `<button>` pelo menos no Firefox são construídos com um elemento interno entre a tag `<button>` e seus filhos. No Firefox é chamado `moz-button-content` não é algo que pode ser alcançado com CSS e foi definido para exibir o bloco sem herdar a altura do botão, você pode ver esta declaração de estilo na [folha de estilo useragent](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/res/forms.css#664-696).

O navegador por padrão já é [codificado para centralizar o conteúdo do botão verticalmente.](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/forms/nsHTMLButtonControlFrame.cpp#289-294)

Com estas duas questões você pode começar a ver como o botão força o conteúdo a ser centralizado, considere:

```
<button>

+------------------------+ ^
| button extra space     | |
|                        | |
+------------------------+ |
|| ::moz-button-content || | button height
||   display: block;    || |
+------------------------+ |
|                        | |
| button extra space     | |
+------------------------+ v
```

Há uma solução alternativa para o problema se você realmente quiser alterar o comportamento padrão, mas isso não resolve completamente o problema dependendo da sua implementação.

Se você inserir um wrapper `<span>` com `display: block` o único filho do botão e colocar todo o seu conteúdo nele, poderá usá-lo para pular o `moz-button-content` elemento.

Você precisará fazer com que este `<span>` elemento tenha `height: inherit` preenchido corretamente a altura do botão e, em seguida, adicionar seu estilo de botão normal ao `<span>` invés disso, você obterá basicamente o comportamento desejado.

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: san-serif;
background: none;
font-size: 1em;
line-height:1;
vertical-align: baseline;
}

button, a {
height: 3em;
}

button {
background: red;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner {
border: 0;
padding: 0;
outline: 0;
}

button > span {
display: block;
height: inherit;
}

a {
display:inline-block;
background: green;
}



button.styled > span , a.styled{
padding: 10px;
background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button>
<span>Button content</span>
</button>

<a>
<span>Link Content</span>
</a>

<br/>
<br/>

<button class="styled">
<span>Button content</span>
</button>

<a class="styled">
<span>Link Content</span>
</a>
```

Você deve usar um em `<span>` vez de um `<div>`, como `div` não são filhos válidos para `<button>`.

Comment: Não amigo acho que vc não entendeu bem a pergunta ou está equivocado. O autor da pergunta quer saber pq o texto dentro do btn fica alinhado na vertical por padrão. E não é por causa do vertical-align, pois mesmo colocando no button por exemplo ` vertical-align: bottom !important` o texto continua centralizado verticalmente no meio do button, logo não é isso que faz o texto do btn alinhar centralizado. Resumindo coloca `vertical-align` no button e tenta alinha o conteúdo que não no centro do btn, não vai funcionar...

Comment: @hugocsl, editei a resposta, peço que analise novamente, realmente achei que era apenas sobre o alinhamento, adicionei novas observações.

Comment: Era bom pôr um snippet aí mas creio que a resposta esteja errada. Vou ligar meu PC daqui a pouco e já testo

Comment: Não creio que seja do sistema operacional, é sim do user-agent default do browser. input, select, checkbox, todos são estilizado pelo user-agent e não pelo sistema operacional, tanto que no safari para windows (mesmo que antigo), os estilos eram iguais aos do Mac, então acho que OS não tem nada a ver com isso... Depois, fazer o `<a>` ficar igual ao `<button>` é bem diferente de fazer o button ficar igual ai A... Para alinhar verticalmente exitem 1000 fórmulas, mas pq o button faz isso por default? pq não tem como mudar isso? Se vc conseguir, posta ai. E se tiver uma fonte ajuda.

Comment: Sobre deixar <button> igual ao <a> olhe novamente a resposta, editei.

Comment: Cara é só dar um all:unset no button, nem precisa escrever tudo isso de css pra "resetar" os estilos padrão do button... mas mesmo zerando tudo o texto continua no centro verticalmente, basta colocar um height no btn que vc vai ver

Comment: @hugocsl atualizado, acho que com a resposta responde tudo, realmente estava entendendo errado e tive que buscar quase a noite inteira pra achar a resposta fiquei atucanado.

Comment: Pega um arquivo sem nenhum css, cria um button, coloca um span dentro com display:block e height 100px. Ele vai ficar alinhado no topo verticalmente depois com     transform: translateY vc alinha onde quiser por exemplo. Colocando um elemento dentro do outro vc pode fazer o que quiser.... O que ainda não ficou claro é pq o texto dentro do btn fica sempre no meio vertical... Apesar do sua boa vontade em ajudar acho que ainda não temos uma resposta.